# Can the Windows 10 desktop be made to look like Windows XP?

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp

All I want to see on my desktop is the PC icon, the Network icon, the Trashcan icon, and a row of much smaller icons for the programs I use, set along some edge of the monitor.  Is that possible with Windows 10?  I want it to resemble Windows XP.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: Is it that you want to make it look like the ["classic" theme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZp4Q.png) or the ["someone threw up in a garbage can" theme](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/6/64/Windows_XP_Luna.png/300px-Windows_XP_Luna.png)? The first should be relatively easy, the latter is not.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?ie=UTF-8&q=windows+10+classic+theme

Comment: Or you can try: [https://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/how-to-make-windows-10-look-like-windows-xp-1790134379](https://fieldguide.gizmodo.com/how-to-make-windows-10-look-like-windows-xp-1790134379)

Comment: I mainly want to get rid of the tiles and have the programs I use be launched from tiny icons on a disappearing taskbar.